# AppStore and Testflight with same certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, app-store, testflight, provisioning-profile

I have an iPhone application currently available on the AppStore. I will be adding some new features to this app, but before I make new version public I want to let some testers test it through Testflight. And, when implementing new features, I will probably fix some bugs on the first version.
So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use the same provisioning profile for both deployments (AppStore and Testflight)?
2. Is it possible to send push notifications simultaneously on both versions or do I have to define separate feeds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not different "versions" or different "deployments". The whole point of TestFlight is that the binary you are testing with TestFlight is identically the same binary that you would release to the App Store if you decided it was good; otherwise, this would not be a valid test! You do not try stuff on TestFlight and then make and upload another build for the Store; you try stuff on TestFlight and then turn around to the Store and say "release *that* one".

Comment: Ok, so it's the same provisioning profile and the same push notification flow. In fact, we just chose to deploy directly to the AppStore or via TestFlight first, right?

Comment: If you are asking what I think you are asking, yes!

Answer (score 0):

1. Is it possible to use the same provisioning profile for both deployments (AppStore and Testflight)?

   **YES**. Same provisioning profile can be used
2. Is it possible to send push notifications simultaneously on both versions or do I have to define separate feeds?

   **YES**. Its possible to send push notifications simultaneously on both versions.